# ASP Classic simple image upload

Tags: ms-access, file-upload, asp-classic, image-uploading

I need to be able to upload images to a folder on a server using Asp classic and then enter its location into a database.
Everything Ive found has been pages and pages of code that I dont understand.
Does anyone know anywhere there is a tutorial on simple uploads?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the freeaspupload class file then you don't need to understand it, you just upload it to your server as is, include it with the include file directive where relevant, then follow the instructions here.

http://www.freeaspupload.net/freeaspupload/documentation.asp.

This question may also help

[How to Insert Record and Upload file using the FreeASPUpload Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271091/how-to-insert-record-and-upload-file-using-the-freeaspupload-script/18283776#18283776)

Alternatively, look at paid for third party components like Persits ASP upload.