# Access form post Data without request.Form

Tags: file-upload, asp-classic

I know this is very weird but I get following error on my page and I know I can't have `Request.form` with `ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"` Cannot call `BinaryRead` after using `Request.Form` collection.

My Actual Uploader page I use Forms collection to access form data like `Uploader.Form("txtTitle")`.

But on this uploder page I have included couple of ASP pages which are standard thruout app for other security checks and etc and those pages use `Request.form`.
What's other alternative to access form post data without `Request.form` on those security pages? Since those are common pages use by all other pages which don't have `ENCTYPE="multipart/form-data"` on their forms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using aspfreeupload.  You might like to take a look at this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18271091/how-to-insert-record-and-upload-file-using-the-freeaspupload-script/18283776#18283776

Comment: no I am not using that one.

Comment: It might help if you provided some code to look at

Answer (score 0):

Put the includes' code which uses Request.Form inside a function, than pass values as parameters to the function instead of using Request.Form

So in your page it will look something like this:

```
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="myinclude.asp"-->
MyIncludeFunction Uploader.Form("MyIncludeFunctionParameter")
```

And in all other pages:

```
<!--#INCLUDE FILE="myinclude.asp"-->
MyIncludeFunction Request.Form("MyIncludeFunctionParameter")
```