# Check if Form is Submitted Without Using the Request.Form Object?

Tags: forms, file-upload, vbscript, asp-classic

Is there a way to determine if a form with id/name X is submitted without checking the `Request.Form` object?

The reason I am asking is because I have some common code (executes on every pageload) which checks if the login/logout form has been submitted, and this conflicts with some file upload pages (because it needs to use `Request.binaryRead` - which can't be used after using `Request.Form`).

How does one typically handle this?

Same Question here, but there are no good answers. 
[Access form post Data without request.Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28902475/access-form-post-data-without-request-form)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [enctype](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-enctype) attribute an HTML Form element affects request's `Content-Type` header which allows you to determine what kind of form is submitted.
So, you simply need to check `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE` server variable.

```vb
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD") = "POST" Then
    'a POST request was made

    If InStr(1, Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE"), "multipart", vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
        'Content-Type header starts with multipart
        'possible file upload form (<form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data ...)
        'using Request.BinaryRead is OK
    Else
        'ordinary HTML form
        'using Request.Form is OK
    End If
End If
```